# How does Spring Batch get the ExecutionContext when restarting a failed job?

Tags: java, spring, serialization, spring-batch

Im trying to restart a job that failed in the last of 20+ steps but Im getting the **JobExecution could not be restarted Unable to deserialize the execution context** error.

Does it try to get it from the Short_Context or Serialized_Context in the BATCH_STEP_EXECUTION_CONTEXT? In case there's something wrong, do I have to fix all previous steps entries or just the one before the failed step?

**UPDATE**:
The SHORT_CONTEXT is incomplete with all values ending with "..." so theyre not a valid JSON which could be causing the error if the restart reads from here. The Serialized_Context is complete and a valid JSON.

Comment: What's the cause of `Unable to deserialize the execution context`? Do you have a stacktrace?

Comment: @MahmoudBenHassine Sadly I dont have any details on the error and we currently dont have the means to replicate it (occurs when a previous partitioner job processes more than 1000 entries) but from what Ive read, the reason must be the JSON context has props from classes not marked as deserializable or it was serialized incorrectly. The last step that failed doesnt need that context so Im looking for a way to "skip" that validation and restart the job without a redeployment